# Cygwin: Obtain comment field from Active Directory with mkpasswd

Tags: active-directory, cygwin, passwd

Running cygwin on W7x64. Since a generated /etc/passwd file is static, it has to be performed occasionally when new employees are hired. It polls Windows AD, and writes the passwd file.

In the past, after running `mkpasswd -l -d > /etc/passwd` it would give (one example):

```
emp1234:unused:<ID>:<GID>:Full Name,U-NET\emp1234,S-1-5-21-6794265879-946158745-9223451784-66123://domctrl/users$/emp1234:/bin/bash
```

Notice how **Full Name** appears in the entry. This was wonderful, because everything in cygwin is coded by the employee code, e.g. **emp1234**. When looking for a file, I can see the last modifier employee code, but if I want to know who it is, I can grep the passwd file.

Now, when I regenerate the passwd file, it gives me this:

```
emp1234:*:<ID>:<GID>:U-NETC\emp1234,S-1-5-21-6794265879-946158745-9223451784-66123:/home/e40182:/bin/bash
```

No more full name! I'm sure I've updated my Cygwin over the last several months, so that could be part of it. But is there a way to have `mkpasswd` specifically ask for the Full Name? According to the Cygwin docs, that slot should be the Comment field on the AD user entry.